# Momentum conservation in spontaneous pair creation and annihilation

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

I know that in free space, photon cannot decay into an electron and a positron since momentum is frame dependent for massive particles while invariant for a photon.

Given this, how is spontaneous pair creation and annihilation possible? Can someone shed some light on it? Or is it that it is actually impossible, and that I had a wrong comprehension?

Comment: This is impossible. Such a process never happens.

Comment: Most references that explain the why it can't happen in free space make at least a passing mention of the loophole that explains why it pair-production processes are observed. Is the problem that you haven't seen such an explnation or that you don't understand why it solves the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Pair creation

You are right: In free space a photon cannot
decay into an electron-positron pair
(because it would violate energy/momentum conservation).

However, *near an atomic nucleus* a photon can decay
into an electron-positron pair.
In this process the atomic nucleus receives some recoil.

See also [Wikipedia: Pair production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production).

The process can be visualized by a Feynman diagram like below.
[image: Feynman diagram of pair production]
<sub>image from [Wikipedia: Pair production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production)</sub>

### Pair annihilation

You are also right, that an electron-positron pair in free space cannot decay
into a photon (again because it would violate energy/momentum conservation).

However, an electron-positron pair can decay into
*two* photons. The two gamma ray photons depart
in roughly opposite directions.

See also [Wikipedia: Electron–positron annihilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron%E2%80%93positron_annihilation).

The process can be visualized by the Feynman diagram below.
[image: Feynman diagram of pair annihilation]
<sub>image from [Feynman diagram for annihilation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109979/feynman-diagram-for-annihilation)</sub>

Comment: Isn't it also possible, although rare, for photons to "collide" and generate a pair; i.e., your pair annihilation diagram run backward?

Comment: @TimWescott Might be possible, but I don't know enough QED to be sure.

Comment: That said there is nothing wrong with a pair combining into an on-shell photon in the precense of a spectator (the time reversal of your upper process), it just has a very small cross-section.

Comment: Also in the upper diagram, the virtual photon interacting with the electron line, could be a virtual graviton , explaining where the energy comes from,  to make the vertex real in the Hawking radiation.